# AppleScript in Automator broken in Big Sur

Tags: applescript, automator

So, I had a pretty simple Automator task that I used from the 'Services' right-click pop-up menu in Finder that copied an image, renamed it, scaled it, then added a border around it. Worked fine for ages. The final step of it is to do the padding in an AppleScript, which starts with this incantation:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set this_image to item 1 of input
...
```

And is meant to continue with `this_image` set to the file path from the previous step.

Since Big Sur, I get an error

```
The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “Can’t get item 1 of {}.”
```

Which seems to indicate that `input` is now an empty list. So — perhaps the previous action (`Rename Finder Items: Replace Text`) does not pass a result — or something else.

Quick search via Google does not yield any clues, except some indication that breaking changes are part of the game and Apple doesn't really indicate what would break.

Any ideas? Every other step works fine — as I single-step, the file is manipulated as expected (duplicated, renamed, scaled, etc.). It's only when it gets to this line where I expect to have a filename in order to do the padding that there's an issue.

(Also, just in case someone wants to suggest using the 'Pad Images' automator action — the padding it performs isn't my kind of padding — it puts padding around the entire image. I just put padding at the top and bottom turning a 3x2 image into a square with the image proper sandwiched between white borders, top and bottom.)

Comment: At the moment, I cannot test in **macOS Big Sur**, however, under **macOS Catalina** a **Rename Finder Items: Replace Test** _action_ **does not** return a result, and I'd expect it to be the same in **macOS Big Sur**. The bottom line is, without seeing your **Automator** _workflow_ I'm not sure how much more help anyone can be.

Comment: What is the best way to share the workflow itself here? I'd be happy to do so.

Comment: One way, not necessary the best way as that is too subjective, but I recently use the free https://gofile.io/uploadFiles to upload a file. Please compress the file before uploading it. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not cross post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites! You posted the same question on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66467309/applescript-in-automator-broken-in-big-sur

Comment: Why is cross-posting discouraged?

Comment: bleeckerj, Please have a look at: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)